# Package Sinatra app into a single JAR file?

Tags: ruby, jruby, sinatra

I've an apparently (silly) simple question:

With JRuby is it possible to deploy a single file Sinatra application?

I mean: I've my Sinatra app with all needed gems exploded into some `./vendor/lib` directory and I'd like to deploy the whole app as a single jar file to run on a deployment machine:

```
$ java jar my_app.jar
```

where the only thing I have is Java.

Is that possible? And, if so, there is a simple way to accomplish that?

TIA

Answer (score 4):

You can try using Warbler for this. As of version 1.1, Warbler supports making a war file "executable". See [the documentation](http://caldersphere.rubyforge.org/warbler/) for details.

Basically, install warbler and try running it on your Sinatra application. If you have a config.ru, everything should pretty much work.

```
$ jruby -S gem install warbler
$ jruby -S warble executable war
$ java -jar my_app.war
```

Comment: TNX, I've already tried that... The only problem appears with some gem "installed" with Bundler (eg: nokogiri).

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy in fact. Suppose you can run your application with everything frozen under some directory with a command:

```
ruby myapp.rb
```

Now you need to place this script into lib directory under your application and write an java wrapper which will load the script. Sample code which does this:

```
package livesync;

import org.jruby.Ruby;
import org.jruby.RubyRuntimeAdapter;
import org.jruby.javasupport.JavaEmbedUtils;  
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LiveSyncRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] jrubyArgs = new String[3 + args.length]; 
        jrubyArgs[0] = "-e";
        jrubyArgs[1] = "require 'livesync/livesync_wrapper'";
        jrubyArgs[2] = "livesync";
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
            jrubyArgs[i + 3] = args[i];
        }
        org.jruby.Main.main(jrubyArgs);
    }
}
```

In case above the script I run is in lib/livesync_wrapper.rb

Now all you need is a proper build.xml file (placed in the root directory)
My build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project basedir="." default="dist" name="Juggernaut">
  <description>Combine Ruby and Java source with the jruby-complete jar</description>
  <target name="dist" description="Create the deliverable jar">
    <taskdef name="jarjar" 
             classname="com.tonicsystems.jarjar.JarJarTask" 
             classpath="vendor/jarjar-1.0rc7.jar"/>
    <mkdir dir="pkg"/>
    <jarjar destfile="pkg/livesync.jar">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="livesync.LiveSyncRunner"/>
      </manifest>
      <fileset dir="classes"/>
      <zipfileset dir="vendor/gems" prefix="vendor/gems"/>
      <zipfileset src="vendor/jruby-complete-1.1.2.jar" />
    </jarjar>
  </target>
</project>
```

Things you might have to change here are:

- name of Main-Class - this have to
  much name of your java wrapper
  (loading ruby script)
- add/remove some zipfilesets

You also need to include files jruby-complete-1.1.2.jar and jarjar-1.0rc7.jar in the vendor directory. You should google them out without any problem.

After doing this you just go to root directory and run ant. After this you can run your script with

```
java -jar pkg/livesync.jar args1 agrs2 ...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks really great, but can you wrap also Ruby Gems as a library and not as executable.
I mean I have ruby library with all kind of functions/methods I want to run from my java server code 
How exactly do I call Ruby functions from within Java including arguments and objects

Comment: Sorry, it's been two years seen I didn't anything with java+jRuby so my knowledge is a little rusty. Anyway, you can find a lot of examples of this being done in this gem source: 
https://github.com/kowalski/redcloth/blob/master/ext/redcloth_scan/redcloth_inline.java.rl
Don't get scared away that this is a template...

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a jruby-complete jar file; unzip the jar.  You can then install your gems into the exploded jar.

jruby.home in the META-INF directory is where the "usual" jruby install is located.  You can use the gem within that directory.

Next, in the jruby.home directory, make a directory, let's call it app and place your app in it.

Next you'll need to create a script to run in the bin directory which starts your application.

*TEST* and make sure everything is working.

Then zip everything back up, creating a file such as app.jar.

Finally, to run:

```
  java -jar app.jar -S YOUR_SCRIPT
```

-or- 
      muck about with the manifest and create a java class which is functionally similar to the script.